# Debian image in QEMU freezes at login on windows 10

Tags: debian, qemu

I have a MacBook pro and Installed Windows 10 using Parallel Desktop 12, Then on my Windows side I installed QEMU Manager and downloaded a SH4 Debian image for it.
But when the Linux image is booting up it freezes at login section.

Here is the command that I use to run the image :

```
C:\> qemu-system-sh4 -M r2d -kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-sh7751r -initrd initrd.img-2.6.32-5-sh7751r -hda debian_sid_sh4_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 noiotrap"
```

I tried Alt-Ctrl-F1....Fn but nothing happened,however alt-ctrl releases the mouse.

The only error that I found during the startup was an error about setting a variable which is not important I guess (following picture)

[image: debian sid sh4 freezes at login]

I have searched the internet but I didn't find anything neither found the answer in other questions having the same issue(freeze at login)

Is it possible to make it work? 
Am I doing a bad practice by running a debian image on QEMU on a Windows which itself is a virtual machine(Parallel Desktop)?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem by installing QEMU on Mac with the following steps :

1. Install Homebrew on OSX
2. Install QEMU Using HomeBrew `brew install qemu` very easy!
3. create a command file with name run_emu_sh4.command
4. set the privilege `chmod 775 run_emu_sh4.command`
5. load the debian image via qemu-system-sh4 that I just installed

My Command file content :

`qemu-system-sh4 -M r2d -kernel /Users/Iman/Documents/QEMU/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-sh7751r -initrd /Users/Iman/Documents/QEMU/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-sh7751r -hda /Users/Iman/Documents/QEMU/debian_sid_sh4_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 noiotrap"`

[image]